# Can a SharePoint 2010 lookup column point to a multi-line rich text field from same list

Tags: workflow, lookup-column

Can a SharePoint 2010 lookup column point to a multi-line rich text field in same list?

i dont find multiline column while creating a lookup column. Is there any way to achieve this. Because my requirement need such a way to add the values that exists in the other column.

Can i use workflow to make this, then give me some suggestions

Comment: The short answer is no, however can you describe what you are trying to do, and maybe we can provide a path forward to you.

Comment: I have a column named "question" and while creating a Add new form i need to add some previously added questions related to the current question. So i tried to create a lookup column and tried to add question column as lookup field. since question is a multiline rich text field it is not possible to add. Convey me some suggestions on this

Comment: is no one got it what i am asking for?

Comment: You can use a calculated column to achieve your desired functionality!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, with a custom product.

First, you can do what Monica suggested - only I wouldn't go with a workflow. It is an overkill to my taste. I would create a new text column (possibly hidden / read only) and use a list item event handler on item updating / creating. you can use the multi line text field `SPField.GetFieldValueAsText` to get the value without HTML decorations!

But, for your solution, allow me to recommend a product that does what you need:
If what you need is more information in the lookup than just 1 text field in order to make the selection (Say, title only doesn't identify the item and you need to see title + notes + status + created by + created date when selecting) - then a dropdown is just not enough for you.

In this case, I can recommend a product that does the lookup using a grid with checkboxes for selection: http://www.kwizcom.com/images/CascadingLookup/CascadingFilteredLookupField/ImageGallery/big/CLF4.jpg

This way, you can set up the lookup to show multiple columns including multiple lines of text columns when viewing or editing the item, but the lookup will still be tied to a simple single line of text column.

Search for "kwizcom cascading lookup plus" in google for examples, or visit: http://www.kwizcom.com/sharepoint-add-ons/sharepoint-cascading-lookup-plus/overview/

Answer (score 0):

If u can save the sub string of the question in single line of text and then lookup on single line of text column ....

Comment: can u explain me little bit clear..

Comment: Let save on item created / edited , start a designer workflow which will take sub string of multi line of text column say 250 characters and populate to single line of text. Next configure your lookup column on single line of text.

Answer (score 0):

Short easy answer is to use a single line text box. There's a 255 character limitation but it should suffice if you're just using it as a question field.