# How to increase the character length of a single line text field

Tags: 2013

I have a SharePoint 2013 list.In that I created a single line text field named Address. I am trying to increase the length of the single line text field.Is it possible? I cannot use a multiline text field as it does not allow me for a look up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a database limit of 255 characters

Comment: Or is it possible to look up a multi line text field?

Comment: I once made a form which had a multilevel textfield but edited the form in infopath , in that it automatically took unlimited lines of text . (You can reduce the size as singletextbox in the form)

Answer (score 5):

You can't increase the single line of text field to more than 255 characters.  You have to use Multiple Lines of text field to store more than that.

If you still want to use single line of text, the workaround I can suggest is instead of Address, you can divide that into Building Name, Street Name, Area Name, State, Pin etc. And add single line of text for each of them.

Comment: Or is it possible to look up a multi line text field?

Comment: check this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72918/can-a-sharepoint-2010-lookup-column-point-to-a-multi-line-rich-text-field-from-s

Comment: Yes, use multiple lines of text, and in its settins set 1 line for editing. It will look like single line text control

Comment: but is it possible to look it up ?

Comment: Hi Dheeraj, have you checked the link?

Comment: That is not exactly what I require...@P S

Answer (score 1):

I once made a form which had a multilevel textfield but edited the form in infopath , in that it automatically took unlimited lines of text . (You can reduce the size as singletextbox in the form).

255 is the the default limit for a default list. You cant alter that.

Comment: Yeah but am not able to alter that more than 255 characters...when I try to change it throws an error..Limit should be between 1 and 255

Comment: Thats why try using infopath once rather than default list-form.